# EditText formatting

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

Now I've got an `EditText` with `TextWatcher` which formats user input as a phone. For example if users input is `89011234567` it will be formatted as `+7 (901) 123-45-67`.

I wonder is there any way I can extend or implement some classes like `CharSequence` or `Editable`or any other like these to make `EditText` display the formatted output, but when I will call `mEditText.getText().toString()` it will return original users input?

Comment: You can extend edittext and add a method like getFormattedText().

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class that extends the standard EditText, and then override the `getText()` method to return what you need.

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {
   //Implement the methods that need implementation. Calling the method in the super class should do the trick

   @Override
   public Editable getText() {
     //return an Editable with the required text.
   }
}
```

Then you just use the `MyEditText` instead of the normal EditText.

This solution will work, if you don't use the `getText()`-method other places (like your TextWatcher).

Comment: Bad for me I didn't think about it. But one question is left. Which method returns the spannable for the EditText to be rendered? And will the copy of this text return my buffer?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question. The standard `getText()` of `EditText` returns an `Editable`-object.

Comment: Try posting your current code for the `TextWatcher` and the places where you need to call the `getText()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the user's input into the tag property of your edittext, this way you could access it and it wouldn't be modified by using setText to display the formatted number !

Comment: Well, currently used method satisfies me. But I thought it might be possible just to override some classes and work with EditText as usual.